# Why doesn't Pattern.matches("[a*mn]","aaaa") return true? What should be proper code to get the desired output?

Tags: java

I want to create a pattern where the desired string should either be multiples of a including null i.e. a*, or it should be one single m or single n. But the following code doesn't give the desired output.

```
class Solution {
            public static void main(String args[]) {
                System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[a*mn]", "aaaa"));
        }
}
```

Comment: `*` is no quantifier when used inside square brackets

Comment: Please, send more example that shows exactly what you want.

Comment: "aaaaa" or "aa" or "m" or "n" should return true but "aaam" or "aaan" or "mmmm" or "nnnn" will return false. only a is allowed to have multiples.

Answer (score 4):

`*` within a character class (`[]`) is just a `*`, not a quantifier.

> I want to create a pattern where the desired string should either be multiples of a including null i.e. a*, or it should be one single m or single n.

You'll need an alternation (`|`) for that: `a*|[mn]`:

```
Pattern.matches("a*|[mn]", "aaaa")
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/vvEYqf):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Example {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        check("aaaa", true);
        check("a", true);
        check("", true);
        check("m", true);
        check("n", true);
        check("mn", false);
        check("q", false);
        check("nnnn", false);
    }
    private static void check(String text, boolean expect) {
        boolean result = Pattern.matches("a*|[mn]", text);
        System.out.println(
            (result ? "Match   " : "No match") +
            (result == expect ? " OK    " : " ERROR ") +
            ": " + text
        );
    }
}
```

...though obviously if you were really using the pattern repeatedly, you'd want to compile it once and reuse the result.

Comment: what does '|' mean in java regex?

Comment: The same as eveywhere else: logical OR

Comment: @HARSHITDANG - As I said above: alternation (e.g., one of two alternatives, "or"), see the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) JavaDoc. The regex above literally means exactly what you wrote: "multiplates of a including null ie.g. a* **or** ... one single m or single n"*. (I'm assuming by "null" you really meant "empty string.")

Answer (score 1):

Try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/pjzRzA/1)

```
(a*)|m|n
```

```java
Pattern.matches("(a*)|m|n", "") // true, match 1st group
Pattern.matches("(a*)|m|n", "a") // true, match 1st group
Pattern.matches("(a*)|m|n", "aaaa") // true, match 1st group
Pattern.matches("(a*)|m|n", "m") // true, match `n`
Pattern.matches("(a*)|m|n", "n") // true, match `m`
Pattern.matches("(a*)|m|n", "man") // false
Pattern.matches("(a*)|m|n", "mn") // false
```

Answer (score 1):

inside the [] the "*" is not a quantifier so you'll get a true if one of the characters in the regex is present therefore the result will be true if the string is "a","*","m" or "n".
And the rest will result in false.
your regex should be:

([aa*]*|[mn])

it will be true only if multiples of "a" are entered including "a*" or a single "m" or "n".
check it by following examples:

```
System.out.println("[aa*]*|[mn]","m");
System.out.println("[aa*]*|[mn]","aaaaa");
System.out.println("[aa*]*|[mn]","a*a*");
```